# Music on my iPhone 5s is gone!

Tags: ios, music, bluetooth

Went to play tunes while working out the other day. I tapped on the Music app to open my playlists and all that appears is an image of a girl with headphones on. No playlists...no songs...no way to proceed to any of my music. Anybody else missing their music via Bluetooth?

Comment: Keep cool. Your Music library wasn't killed. You are just facing a big bug in Music interface which should display you a menu proposing to exit, but doesn't. •• return •• If your problem does look exactly like this one http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238587/22003 , just add a comment with any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it happened to me also. After you launch the app, wait a few seconds and it will give you the option to join Apple Music, or go to your music. Click "Go To My Music" and you will be all set. If you don't see these options make sure you have an Internet connection and wait a few seconds.

Comment: Same problem (described here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238587/22003 ). The waiting trick didn't do anything in my case. I am still investing since a quarter of an hour and the problem is still sticking on the screen.